# Autcomplete for Ionic searchbar WITHOUT angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, autocomplete

Is it possible to have autocomplete in Ionic search bar without using Angular. I am making a Vanilla JS application in which I want to show YouTube suggestions as suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thinking and coding, I made a working example.
Here is the code :

```js
const searchbar = document.querySelector('ion-searchbar');
const items = Array.from(document.querySelector('ion-list').children);
searchbar.addEventListener('ionInput', handleInput);

searchbar.addEventListener('ionBlur', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("ion-list").style.display = "none";
  }, 250); //timeout so that the user can click an item
});
searchbar.addEventListener('ionFocus', function() {
  document.querySelector("ion-list").style.display = "block";
});

function handleInput(event) {
  document.querySelector("ion-list").style.display = "block";
  const query = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    items.forEach(item => {
      const shouldShow = item.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1;
      item.style.display = shouldShow ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
  });
}
//intializing the click event for all list items
items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(item.innerHTML);
    document.querySelector("ion-list").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("ion-searchbar").value = item.innerHTML;
  })
});
```

```css
ion-list {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100vw;
}

ion-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Searchbar</title>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />
  <style>
     :root {
      --ion-safe-area-top: 20px;
      --ion-safe-area-bottom: 22px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-header translucent>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Searchbar</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content fullscreen>
      <ion-list style="display:none">
        <ion-item>Amsterdam</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Bogota</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Buenos Aires</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Cairo</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Dhaka</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Edinburgh</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Geneva</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Genoa</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Glasgow</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Hanoi</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Hong Kong</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Islamabad</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Istanbul</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Jakarta</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Kiel</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Kyoto</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Le Havre</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Lebanon</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Lhasa</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Lima</ion-item>
        <ion-item>London</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Los Angeles</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Madrid</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Manila</ion-item>
        <ion-item>New York</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Olympia</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Oslo</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Panama City</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Peking</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Philadelphia</ion-item>
        <ion-item>San Francisco</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Seoul</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Taipeh</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Tel Aviv</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Tokio</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Uelzen</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Washington</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-card><img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/card/madison.jpg" />
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-subtitle>Dummy content</ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-title>Some content</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nisi arcu, hendrerit ac enim sit amet, feugiatdapibus turpis. Nullam a enim finibus, lobortis neque et, hendrerit quam. Nam commodo nibh ut rhoncus consequat. Crassed diam id
          velit aliquet convallis at vel ligula. Nullam eleifend mi justo, non dignissim ligula gravida in. Phasellusa ultricies massa. Nulla pulvinar iaculis urna, in posuere tortor gravida nec. Suspendisse dapibus risus id purusinterdum, in ultricies
          mauris rutrum. Curabitur consequat nunc quam, non auctor nulla venenatis ac. Mauris a nislsollicitudin, condimentum purus id, ultricies est. Quisque et aliquet mauris. Vivamus nec quam non ex dictum ornare.Morbi et erat nec felis tincidunt cursus
          vitae vitae dolor. Aliquam in turpis non diam euismod efficitur vel ac ex.Proin ac tincidunt sem, ac maximus velit.
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-app>
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If any issues occur please notify me.
I think the code is self explanatory, Happy coding!